# targetAttributeName attribute not defined

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

why the targetAttributeName is not recognized in my composite component

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

    <!-- INTERFACE -->
    <cc:interface componentType="myComponentExample">
      <cc:targetAttributeName..../>
    </cc:interface>
..
```

I see this:  **"The component library Composite Components does not
contain component targetAttributeName"**

As i can see i dont have the targetAttributeName and clientBehaviour
attributes, why?

**Im using Netbeans 7.1, MyFaces 2.1.8 and TomEE 1.0 (trunk update)**

This attribute is since JSF 2.1, but i cant use it

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

         <!--Apache MyFaces-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I only can see this attributes:

- name
- class
- default
- displayName
- expert
- id
- method-signature
- parent
- preferred
- rendered
- renderType
- required
- shortDescription
- targets
- transient
- type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tag doesn't exist at all. You're most likely confusing an attribute of `<cc:attribute>` being a separate tag.

```
<cc:attribute targetAttributeName="..." />
```

To learn about all tags (and attributes!) available in JSF 2.1, head to the [VDL documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/).